# ¿How to prevent JQuery datatable reset styles that I made when I click on a pagination button or heading column?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datatables

**Note:** Is not necessary see all the HTML code, is big because I want show many pages for a description of my problem.

I'm only using the filter and pagination functionality of datatables, I'm not require styles, I'm want to put the styles for my own. But I have a problem, When I click some of the pagination links or heading for sorting, the styles that I put on pagination links are gone and I don't know why.

I've tried to put !important keyword for my styles win the specificity but this doesn't work.

Are there some method for my styles not be reset when I click it?

Here is my code, the styles html and the initialization of the plugin:

```js
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.fn.DataTable.ext.pager.numbers_length = 5
            $('#news').DataTable({
                rowReorder: true,
                dom: '<<"filter-controls-wrapper"f><"table-box" t><"pagination-wrapper"p>>'
              
            });
            
            let paginationElements = document.querySelectorAll("#news_paginate > span .paginate_button");

            paginationElements.forEach(function (value, key, nodeList) {
                value.setAttribute("class", "label-page")
                value.setAttribute("id","toggle-" + key)
               
            })
            // window.filterControls.appendChild(window.filterOptions);
            // window.paginationControl.appendChild(window.paginationOptions);
        });
```

```css
        body {
            display: flex;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            padding-left: 1rem;
            padding-right: 1rem;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            height: 100vh;
            background-color: #ffffff;
            font-family: san-serif;
        }

        .table-box {
            width: 890px;
            height: 400px;
            overflow-y: scroll;
            box-shadow: 0 10px 100px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
        }

        table {
            width: 100%;
        }

        table,
        th,
        td {
            border: 1px solid #005277;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }

        tr th:nth-child(1) {
            backround-color: pink;
        }

        th {
            background-color: #1e305b;
            color: white;
        }

        th,
        td {
            padding: 10px;
        }

        thead {
            position: sticky;
            top: 0;
        }

        .news-section {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-rows: ""
        }

        .filter-controls-wrapper {
            margin-bottom: 16px;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: flex-end;
        }


        input[type="search"] {
            border: 1px solid transparent;
            border-radius: 2rem;
            padding-bottom: 5px;
            padding-left: 16px;
            padding-right: 16px;
            padding-top: 16px;
            padding-bottom: 16px;
            transition: 0.2s border-color ease-in-out;
        }

        * {
            font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
        }

        label {
            font-size: 24px;
        }

        input[type="search"]:focus {
            border-color: navy;

        }


        /*PAgination here*/
        .label-page {
            width: 80px ;
            height: 25px ;
            margin: 0 10px ;
            border-radius: 999px ;
            background: crimson ;
            cursor: pointer;
            box-shadow:
                0 5px 5px -5px rgba(crimson, 0.15),
                0 10px 10px -5px rgba(crimson, 0.15),
                0 15px 15px -5px rgba(crimson, 0.15),
                0 20px 20px -5px rgba(crimson, 0.15) ;
            transition: 0.25s ease;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            color: #fff;
            padding: 10px;
        }

        [id*="toggle-"]:hover{
            width: 120px;
        }

        .dataTables_paginate {
            margin-top: 16px;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
        }
        .dataTables_paginate span{
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
        }
```

```html
    <table id="news">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Titulo</th>
                <th>Opciones</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>
                    <a href="#"><span class="fa fa-edit"></span></a>
                    <a href="#"><span class="fa fa-eye-slash"></span></a>
                    <a href="#"><span class="fa fa-trash"></span></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>
                    <a href="#"><span class="fa fa-edit"></span></a>
                    <a href="#"><span class="fa fa-eye-slash"></span></a>
                    <a href="#"><span class="fa fa-trash"></span></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>6</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                <td>41</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Airi Satou</td>
                <td>55</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>6</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>2</td>
            </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>6</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                <td>41</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Airi Satou</td>
                <td>55</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>6</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>2</td>
            </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>6</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                <td>41</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Airi Satou</td>
                <td>55</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>6</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>2</td>
            </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>6</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                <td>41</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Airi Satou</td>
                <td>55</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>6</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>2</td>
            </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>6</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                <td>41</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Airi Satou</td>
                <td>55</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>6</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>2</td>
            </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>6</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                <td>41</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Airi Satou</td>
                <td>55</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>6</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>2</td>
            </tr>    <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>6</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                <td>41</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Airi Satou</td>
                <td>55</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>6</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>2</td>
            </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>6</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                <td>41</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Airi Satou</td>
                <td>55</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>6</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>2</td>
            </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>6</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                <td>41</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Airi Satou</td>
                <td>55</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>6</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>2</td>
            </tr>
        
        </tbody>
        
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/rowreorder/1.2.6/js/dataTables.rowReorder.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you change the class of the pagination buttons and apply your style to this 'custom' class. That only works once because datatable redraws the buttons each time you navigate and your custom class disapears.

```
    let paginationElements = document.querySelectorAll("#news_paginate > span .paginate_button");

    paginationElements.forEach(function (value, key, nodeList) {
        value.setAttribute("class", "label-page")
        value.setAttribute("id","toggle-" + key)

    })
```

Removing this whole block of code and applying your style to the default `.pagination_button` resolves your problem.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
            $.fn.DataTable.ext.pager.numbers_length = 5
            $('#news').DataTable({
                rowReorder: true,
                dom: '<<"filter-controls-wrapper"f><"table-box" t><"pagination-wrapper"p>>'
              
            });

            // window.filterControls.appendChild(window.filterOptions);
            // window.paginationControl.appendChild(window.paginationOptions);
        });
```

```css
body {
            display: flex;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            padding-left: 1rem;
            padding-right: 1rem;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            height: 100vh;
            background-color: #ffffff;
            font-family: san-serif;
        }

        .table-box {
            width: 890px;
            height: 400px;
            overflow-y: scroll;
            box-shadow: 0 10px 100px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
        }

        table {
            width: 100%;
        }

        table,
        th,
        td {
            border: 1px solid #005277;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }

        tr th:nth-child(1) {
            backround-color: pink;
        }

        th {
            background-color: #1e305b;
            color: white;
        }

        th,
        td {
            padding: 10px;
        }

        thead {
            position: sticky;
            top: 0;
        }

        .news-section {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-rows: ""
        }

        .filter-controls-wrapper {
            margin-bottom: 16px;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: flex-end;
        }


        input[type="search"] {
            border: 1px solid transparent;
            border-radius: 2rem;
            padding-bottom: 5px;
            padding-left: 16px;
            padding-right: 16px;
            padding-top: 16px;
            padding-bottom: 16px;
            transition: 0.2s border-color ease-in-out;
        }

        * {
            font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
        }

        label {
            font-size: 24px;
        }

        input[type="search"]:focus {
            border-color: navy;

        }


        /*PAgination here*/
        span .paginate_button {
            width: 80px ;
            height: 25px ;
            margin: 0 10px ;
            border-radius: 999px ;
            background: crimson ;
            cursor: pointer;
            box-shadow:
                0 5px 5px -5px rgba(crimson, 0.15),
                0 10px 10px -5px rgba(crimson, 0.15),
                0 15px 15px -5px rgba(crimson, 0.15),
                0 20px 20px -5px rgba(crimson, 0.15) ;
            transition: 0.25s ease;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            color: #fff;
            padding: 10px;
        }

        [id*="toggle-"]:hover{
            width: 120px;
        }

        .dataTables_paginate {
            margin-top: 16px;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
        }
        .dataTables_paginate span{
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
        }
```

```html
<table id="news">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Titulo</th>
                <th>Opciones</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>
                    <a href="#"><span class="fa fa-edit"></span></a>
                    <a href="#"><span class="fa fa-eye-slash"></span></a>
                    <a href="#"><span class="fa fa-trash"></span></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>
                    <a href="#"><span class="fa fa-edit"></span></a>
                    <a href="#"><span class="fa fa-eye-slash"></span></a>
                    <a href="#"><span class="fa fa-trash"></span></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>6</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                <td>41</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Airi Satou</td>
                <td>55</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>6</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>2</td>
            </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>6</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                <td>41</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Airi Satou</td>
                <td>55</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>6</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>2</td>
            </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>6</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                <td>41</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Airi Satou</td>
                <td>55</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>6</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>2</td>
            </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>6</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                <td>41</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Airi Satou</td>
                <td>55</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>6</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>2</td>
            </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>6</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                <td>41</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Airi Satou</td>
                <td>55</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>6</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>2</td>
            </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>6</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                <td>41</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Airi Satou</td>
                <td>55</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>6</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>2</td>
            </tr>    <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>6</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                <td>41</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Airi Satou</td>
                <td>55</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>6</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>2</td>
            </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>6</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                <td>41</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Airi Satou</td>
                <td>55</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>6</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>2</td>
            </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>6</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                <td>41</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Airi Satou</td>
                <td>55</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>6</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>2</td>
            </tr>
        
        </tbody>
        
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/rowreorder/1.2.6/js/dataTables.rowReorder.min.js"></script>
```